# how to add C++ cgi library to MinGW compiler?

Tags: c++, windows-10, mingw, cgi

I couldn't find any help from google when I search for adding cgi library to Mingw compiler in windows10. Cany anyone help me to add the library to MinGw compiler?

Please give me step by step instruction as I am new to cgi.

Comment: Normally the only you need to do is to give to the compiller -L flag with the path where the libraries (*so) files are located, and -I with the path to the headers of your library. I would not expect anything else.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @dmi . But as I am new to this, I am not sure how to set -L flag as you mentioned. If you give me step by step instruction, it'll be really helpful for me.

Comment: These are the command line options to the compiller. Generally this looks like `gcc -L/path/to/cgi/lib -I/path/to/cgi/include myfile.cpp` or something like that. You can google what command line options your compiller supports. Just man gcc.